# Not able to accessing internet from native blackberry simulator

Tags: testing, blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

I am getting the following message on accessing internet from native blackberry simulator.

> **"Unable to connect to the internet please try again later. If the problemt persists please contact your service provide."**

Getting this issue on blackberry standalone simulator for 9860. I have not installed JDE or any other Dev tool. Seen lots of comments asking for adding the proxy details on HTTP HEADER, but it didnt work for me. I am trying in corporate network having proxy

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to install and run the BlackBerry MDS? https://swdownloads.blackberry.com/Downloads/entry.do?code=F9BE311E65D81A9AD8150A60844BB94C

You have to run it BEFORE running the simulator to be able to use the internet connection.

Comment: THis doesnt work for me :-( Getting the same issue. Now the message got changed. sating that the 'Server is too busy to accept the request...'

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this on your simulator:

1) Go to "Manage Connections"
2) Click "Set Up Wi-Fi Network"
3) Either click "Default WLAN Network" if you see it there or create it using "Manually Connect to Network"

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am able to browse some corporate sites from Blackberry simulator but not able to browse other sites even google. I have configured proxy details in rimpublic.property. Plzzzz Help

Comment: @Hashili you could be behind some proxy settings. Try this:

Go to MDS folder i.e. where it is installed, go to rim public property config file, add your proxy server settings save and restart.
Launch MDS & Device Simulator.

Maybe this will work.